# What is the current zle keymap/mode?

Tags: zsh, zle

For example, if I hit the right combination of keys to enter `viins` and walk away from the terminal and forget, how can I tell when I get back? How can I tell what the default mode is? The guide has this:

> If you’re in the wrong mode, ‘bindkey -e’ in ~/.zshrc takes you to emacs mode and ‘bindkey -v’ to vi mode.

But what *is* the mode? I'd like to know before typing. The $KEYMAP special variable is, as far as I can see, only available *within* zle widgets, and I can find nothing in `man zshzle` nor the zshell user guide as to how to tell what the current mode is.

Any help or insight will be much appreciated.

Comment: See [make my zsh prompt show mode in vi mode](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/547)

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: do a `bindkey -lL main` and you'll see the name of the keymap before the word `main`.

From my reading of the [docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Keymaps) it seems that the "current" keymap is denoted by the name `main`. This is typically aliased to either the `viins` or `emacs` keymap.

Further [down](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zle-Builtins) it states:

> `-l`                *(lowercase ‘L’)*
>
> List all existing keymap names; if any arguments are given, list just those keymaps.
>
> If the `-L` option is also used,
> list in the form of bindkey commands to create or link the keymaps. 
> ‘`bindkey -lL main`’ shows which keymap is linked to ‘`main`’, if any,
> and hence if the standard emacs or vi emulation is in effect. 
> This option does not show the `.safe` keymap
> because it cannot be created in that fashion;
> however, neither is ‘`bindkey -lL .safe`’ reported as an error,
> it simply outputs nothing.

So, if you do a `bindkey -lL` you'll see that (in normal circumstances) one of the keymaps is aliased (via `bindkey -A`) to `main` which is the "current" keymap.

If the `main` keymap doesn't exist, you are dropped into the `.safe` keymap,
which is very unfriendly but will function well enough for you to fix things. 
If this happens to you, `bindkey -d` should reset your keymap situation.